# how to get function arg from external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

below code is in one javascript file
==> test.js:

```
function test(){    window.open('http://example.com/abc/c4adbeb687f77b48a041d70395803358','','toolbar=yes,statusbar=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,fullscreen=yes');}
```

how can i get `http://example.com/abc/c4adbeb687f77b48a041d70395803358` from a html file with below structure
==>test.html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script>
alert(window.open.value);
</script>
```

Comment: Is it a chaning js, or your code will be everytime on the same position?
And is there any of your function call you need, or there is only one?

Comment: A little confused here.But, Window.open just opens a window. Calling it a second time, opens a second window... technically. I guess the main question here is: What do you plan to do with this text from the url you provided. There are many way to rip the text into javascript, then you can parse it any number of ways as well, in order to extract whatever information you like.

Comment: Thinking about it again, are you saying you want to grab the url that is located in `test.js` and do something with it?

Comment: I think this is just an example what he need. I guess its an external js, like jquery, and he wants to get something from it. This was also just another example, but really it doesnt have effect if grabs something from a local code.

Comment: my mean is : can get content of external javascript files? or on main question can get url in window.open function?

Comment: yes this is just an example . the javascript file is an dynamic file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems a bit unclear.... to me.

I presume you are trying to rip the url that is located in a `.js` file. In your example you want the url `http://example.com/abc/c4adbeb687f77b48a041d70395803358` to be ripped out of `test.js`.

Well, in your example, you have `test.js` loaded as its in the script tag as you showed here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Therefore, if you know the name of the function that has the url data. You can simply:

```
alert(test.toSource());
```

to see its contents. However, it will need to be parsed. One could write a weird looking RegEx expression for it. But, here is a workaround:

```
alert("http"+test.toSource().split("http")[1].split("',")[0]);
```

This is a ROUGH workaround. Parsing heavily depends on how people write code. And, in this example, if they used a `"` instead of `'` then it would not display the url correctly. There could be other issues, a nice RegEx could knock it out cleanly tho.

However, if you dont know the functions name. And you just want to blindly search the whole `js` file for a url (specific or in general), then I would suggest it best to load it with `XMLHttpRequest`. I guess there is a `HttpRequest` you could use as well, never looking into it.

```
var sUrl = "test.js";
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("GET",sUrl, true);
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) { // ok
                alert ( "http"+httpRequest.responseText.split("http")[1].split("',")[0] );
            } else if ( httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status != 200  ) {
                // failed
            }   
        };
httpRequest.send(null);
```

That mess should show an alert box containing the first appearing http url in a function argument from any URL put into `sUrl`.

If you want more... then that means more parsing. But you can store it from here to do whatever.

But, once you open a window from javascript, you cannot access this new window's contents from within the opening javascript. Cross Domain violation
(some sort of extension of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). You can, however, change where its pointing. And, grab the location its pointed to, which might also be what your asking here.

In that case, if the window is already open you can do this

```
var w = window.open("http:\\example.com"); // some time before
alert(w.location);
```

However, if you just opened it. Like above. It might be `about:blank`, because it hasn't loaded yet. In which case you would have to look for it later.. like:

```
window.open("http:\\example.com", "MyName");
setTimeout('var w = window.open(,"MyName"); alert(w.location);', 1000);
```

Here, you have to use the window name parameter for `window.open`. Then, the second time you call `window.open` you leave the URL parameter blank and only use the window name parameter to get a reference to an existing open window... instead of opening a new one.

Then, if you want to ubiquitously grab all urls passed into `window.open`, there is a hijack method. It all just depends on what your asking here... but Kroltan beat me to it! lol! So check his answer for that one.

PT

Comment: Interesting how the accepted answer got no comments, nor votes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over both the HTML and the JS, you can intercept the `window.open` function:

```
<script>
var oldWindowOpen = window.open;
var windowOpenArgs = [];
window.open = function() {
    windowOpenArgs = arguments;
    oldWindowOpen.call(window, arguments);
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script>
window.open = oldWindowOpen;
// do stuf with variable windowOpenArgs
console.log(windowOpenArgs[0]); //the url
</script>
```

You could get more advanced, by throwing and catching a error to find the stack trace and only record the parameters when the call comes from a specific function, but it all depends on the nature of your scripts:

```
window.open = function() {
    try { throw new Error(); } except(e) {
        var stack = e.stack;
        if (/test@.*?test.js:/.test(stack)) {
            windowOpenArgs = arguments;
        }
    }
}
```

However notice that the variable will only be set *after* `test()` is executed!

Comment: I thought this may be what the OP wanted, but the question is really poorly asked, so I didn't post an answer

Comment: From the comments I'm not sure this is what the OP wants... The OP seems to be more interested in retrieving the content of the JavaScript file and parsing it.

Comment: Hence, my answer. Ya, I hadn't yet got to the hijack method before this one was posted, was still adding to mine! Lol! so vague makes for many possibilities!

Comment: Well, let's wait for his decision, then. Whatever he wants to do, it's not a very great thing to do.